# How to determine why HP DataVault X510 WHS fails to boot?

Tags: boot, windows-home-server

I have a HP DataVault X510 Windows Home Server that does not appear to boot up any more. It turns on displays all three lights (power, network & health) for a couple of seconds then turns off for a couple of seconds and tries to boot up again.

I have checked the network port by plugging it into my laptop and it works fine. I have also tried clicking the status/recovery button on the front to either get some status lights or boot the server into recovery mode but that has not had any effect.

Please find a short video of the bootup sequence here:
http://youtu.be/djQ8-JFJkrg

How can I determine why it is not booting/how to fix it?

Comment: Do the HDDs spin up?

Comment: It sounds like they start spinning up before it 'reboots'. I also tried turning it on without the drives in and it does exactly the same thing.

Comment: You might see if HP has a user manual or other document that could help...http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/pfinder?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&tool=&query=DataVault+X510

Comment: @Moab thanks, first thing i did was download manual but only suggestion in there is trying the status/recovery button to either see what the error code is or perform a recovery/factory reset however that doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has a similar issue it turns out HP has a dedicated 24/7 support number for the X500 series. I was told the above meant my server was dead and I was sent a replacement chassis.

For [Australia](http://www8.hp.com/au/en/contact-hp/phone-assist.html#section1):

> HP MediaSmart Server & HP StorageWorks DataVault 1 800 83 9667 24
>   hours a day, 7 days a week ( English only )

For other countries [Contact HP Support](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/hp-information/summary/ww-contact-us.html)